# XPS file too big to be stored in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database

I'm trying to store a `.xps` file in a SQL Server database, but I get the error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'String or binary data would be truncated.'

I know this means the data I want to store is too big, but I've also tried serializing the document and it's still too large (my datatype is `varchar(MAX)`):

```
var xpsDocument = new XpsDocument(xpsFile, FileAccess.Read);
String toSave;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new XpsSerializerFactory().CreateSerializerWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
    toSave = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
}

con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "insert into [table] values('" + filename + "', '" + toSave + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

`filename` is just `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog.FileName)` - my datatype for that column is `varchar(20)` and its length is definitely within that range.

Is there any other way I could further reduce the size of the string? If not, is there a different way to store xps files in a database?

Edit based on msd's answer:

```
byte[] toSave;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var writer = new XpsSerializerFactory().CreateSerializerWriter(ms);
    writer.Write(xpsDocument.GetFixedDocumentSequence());
    toSave = ms.ToArray();
}

con.Open();

const String preparedCommand = "insert into [table] values(@FileName, @File, '', '', '', '')";

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = toSave;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Doesn't your database support BLOBs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing the way I added parameters to my query.

```
 using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("insert into [table] values(@FileName, @File, '" + fileSizeDisplayed + "', '" + current.ToString(dtformat) + "', 'no', 'no')", con))
    {
        SqlParameter file2 = new SqlParameter("@File", file);
        SqlParameter filename2 = new SqlParameter("@FileName", filename);
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add(filename2);
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add(file2);
        sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change data type to `VARBINARY(MAX)` and use the following method to insert your file(as memory Stream) into database

```
public static void databaseFilePut(MemoryStream file, string fileName) 
{
   int varID = 0;
   byte[] file = fileToPut.ToArray();
   const string preparedCommand = 
              @"insert into [table] values(@FileName, @File, '', '', '', '')";
   using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
        using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand(preparedCommand, varConnection)) {
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
            sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, file.Length).Value = fileName;
             sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** With File Stream

```
public static void databaseFilePut(string varFilePath) {
    byte[] file;
    using (var stream = new FileStream(varFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream)) {
            file = reader.ReadBytes((int) stream.Length);       
        }          
    }
    using (var varConnection = Locale.sqlConnectOneTime(Locale.sqlDataConnectionDetails))
    using (var sqlWrite = new SqlCommand("insert into [table] values(@FileName, @File, '', '', '', '')", varConnection)) {
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.VarBinary, file.Length).Value = file;
        sqlWrite.Parameters.Add("@FileName", SqlDbType.VarChar, file.Length).Value = Path.GetFileName(varFilePath);
        sqlWrite.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Same error, I updated my code to show what I changed - did I do it wrongly?

Comment: Still the same error :/ - I did a `Console.Write` of file's length and it returned 1298925; think it's just too big to be stored.

Comment: @cosmo, out of curiosity, were you writing the `toSave.Length` to the console? `VARBINARY(MAX)` should be able to handle that file size as it is not much larger than 1 MB. What do you get for `filename.Length`?

Comment: @Poosh Yes, I used toSave.Length. filename.Length returned 11.

Answer (score 0):

Translate your nvarchar(max) with text. Your problem will solve.

Comment: Could you try for debug? Then tell me please problem starts at which code?

Comment: It starts at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Do your datatype like nvarchar(MAX) not varchar.

Comment: I tried nvarchar(MAX), varbinary(MAX), text, ntext; none worked.